# Error java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found when call retrofit in background

Tags: android, react-native, retrofit

error when replying from fcm notification in the background then call retrofit, and got error **onFailure** callback.

strangely when foreground does not error

code call retrofit:

```
protected void replyToMessage(final Ejson ejson, final int notId, final CharSequence message) {
        String serverURL = ejson.serverURL();
        String rid = ejson.rid;

        if (serverURL == null || rid == null) {
            return;
        }

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        String json = buildMessage(rid, message.toString(), ejson);

        CustomPushNotification.clearMessages(notId);

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("x-auth-token", ejson.token())
                .header("x-user-id", ejson.userId())
                .url(String.format("%s/api/v1/chat.sendMessage", serverURL))
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.i("RCNotification", String.format("Reply FAILED exception %s", e.getMessage()));
                onReplyFailed(notificationManager, notId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("RCNotification", "Reply SUCCESS");
                    onReplySuccess(notificationManager, notId);
                } else {
                    Log.i("RCNotification", String.format("Reply FAILED status %s BODY %s", response.code(), response.body().string()));
                    onReplyFailed(notificationManager, notId);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

any solution?

Comment: I have some problem.